# TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/ Caught SyntaxError while rendering: invalid syntax

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls

I have an app names blogspot and when ever I add the urls related to this app, into the project urls.py file I get the above given error. The code for the urls.py file for the blogspot app is

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from blogspot.models import UserBlog
from tagging.views import tagged_object_list
from hitcount.views import update_hit_count_ajax

info_dict =
{
    'queryset': UserBlog.objects.filter(status=1),
    'date_field': 'pub_date',
}

urlpatterns = patterns('',                      
    url(r'^new/$', 'blogspot.views.blog_form' , name = 'blog_new'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<blog_id>\d+)/$', 'blogspot.views.blog_form',  name = 'blog_edit'),
    url(r'^delete/(?P<blog_id>\d+)/$', 'blogspot.views.blog_delete', name = 'blog_delete'),                       
    url(r'^all/$', 'blogspot.views.all_blogs', name =  'blog_all'),
    url(r'^view/(?P<blog_id>\d+)/$', 'blogspot.views.blog_view', name = 'blog_view'),
    url(r'^ajax/hit/$',update_hit_count_ajax,name='hitcount_update_ajax'), 
)

urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',

    url(r'(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>w{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-w]+)/$', 'object_detail', dict(info_dict, slug_field='slug',template_name='blogspot/detail.html')),
    url(r'^(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>w{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-w]+)/$', 'object_detail', dict(info_dict, template_name='blogspot/list.html')),
    url(r'^(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>w{1,2})/$','archive_day',dict(info_dict,template_name='blogspot/list.html')),
    url(r'^(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/$','archive_month', dict(info_dict, template_name='blogspot/list.html')),
    url(r'^(?P<year>d{4})/$','archive_year', dict(info_dict, template_name='blogspot/list.html')),
    url(r'^$','archive_index', dict(info_dict, template_name='blogspot/list.html')),
)
```

I don't understand, how adding this url file is messing up with the admin urls as well.

**Update**

When I remove all the lines from urls.py file, then everything is running fine. However even if I add one line the whole thing goes rogue. I don't understand there is no syntax error even then it is not working.

**More Update**

I think this problem maybe because of the views.py file of the app because, each other py file has it's .pyc file but not the views.py file. Syntactically there is no error in the urls.py file.

Answer (score 2):

An error in your URL file can give that error message, due to the way things are imported.

In the example you posted, you're missing a closing brace at the end. If that's just from copying and pasting, try commenting each line out, then re-introducing them in turn to find which one is causing the problem.

Comment: No the closing braces that I am missing out here is accidental. The same error is not existing in the actual file. I have updated the above post as well. Although I did not remove each and every line one by one, but I did try removing each of the 2 blocks, but I was still getting the error. So it means there must be an error in both of the urlpatters

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem. Discovered it was an error in my views file.